# Font size medium in css

Tags: html, css, font-size

How does the `font-size` *medium/small/large* work in css? If the  css has a `font-size:11px`, then what is the `font-size:medium` for other elements, does it depend on the  font size, or is it unrelated to  font size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the CSS 'font-size: medium' set font to .Body font size or to the *browser*'s base font size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94241/does-the-css-font-size-medium-set-font-to-body-font-size-or-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's based on the user's preferred font size in their browser, which is probably set to 11 or 12.

See here too for more info [Does the CSS 'font-size: medium' set font to .Body font size or to the *browser*'s base font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94241/does-the-css-font-size-medium-set-font-to-body-font-size-or-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 4):

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-size-props):

> An <absolute-size> keyword is an index to a table of font sizes computed and kept by the UA.

and

> The 'medium' value is the **user's preferred font size** and is used as the reference middle value.

So it doesn't depend on the body font-size.

Answer (score -2):

The font-size in body is the font-size for your entire site, if I understand your question correctly.

You can easily set a different font-size for other elements, classes or ID's

```
p { 
  font-size: medium;
}

h1 {
  font-size: large;
}

#leftBox { 
   font-size: 12px; 
}
```

Although I would never use a static value. I always use a px value.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

Answer (score -3):

Use em in your css. You must set the body's font-size using px then all the containing elements should have font-size setted using em.

Comment: The poster didn't ask about CSS typo best practices (btw, if you're talking about ems and best practices in 2022, you should also mention rems), but about how a specific CSS feature works.